# How to check session in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, iframe

I have a page named Index And a page chat
for check session write the code for print `echo session->user;`
this code work in chat.php but include chat.php in index.php `echo session->user;` not work

```
e:g

  //index.php
<?php
 <iframe src="./chat.php"></iframe> 
enter code here
?>

//chat.php

<?php
include_once ('./session.php');
echo $session->user;
?>
```

`chat.php` printed user but `index.php` not print

Where is the problem?
Please help

While this problem is in Firefox not in IE problem

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works for iframe, start the session like this:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

in chat.php and index.php remember to include

```
session_start()
```

unless it is automatically started in your php.ini

[session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I've already written the session_start() in chat and index.php but not work